# Why can't g++ cannot find the glfw3 library correctly in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, g++, glfw

I am a newbie in Ubuntu, and I have been programming with glfw3 in Mac until now. The problem is as follows. After I downloaded the glfw3 package with

```
sudo aptitude install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev
```

on Ubuntu, I checked the location of the glfw3 library. I googled online and I found out that `dpkg --listfiles packagename` returns the path of all the files related to the package I installed. The result of `dpkg --listfiles libglfw3` is this. (I will just show the paths with the .so files)

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3
```

The result of `dpkg --listfiles libglfw3-dev` is this.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so
```

There are 3 types of .so files, so I wanted to use the most recent one(3.2), and the makefile using the 3.2 version worked so well in Mac. Here is the makefile I tried to use in Ubuntu

```
LINK_TARGET = Animation

OBJS = glad.o Animation.o

REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)

INCLUDES = -I/usr/include

all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All successfully linked!

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $@ $^ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ldl -lglfw.3.2

Animation.o : Animation.cpp
    g++ -c Animation.cpp $(INCLUDES)

glad.o : glad.c
    g++ -c glad.c $(INCLUDES)

clean :
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)
    echo Clean done!
```

If we focus on the line

```
$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $@ $^ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ldl -lglfw.3.2
```

The `-lglfw.3.2` option used to work so well in Mac (Mac used to be .dylib files instead of .so files though. The `-ldl` flag also wasn't needed in Mac too). Now, it prints the error message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3.2` if the makefile is ran.

The makefile successfully runs if I change the option `-lglfw3.2` to `-lglfw` though, and I don't understand why. `libglfw.so.3.2` and `libglfw.so` both existed in the directory. I want to understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that using `-lglfw3.2` will try to link it with `libglfw3.2.so` and not `libglfw.so.3.2`. Even though you can link using that specific version (it's possible to pass the `.so` file directly for linking, ideally statically) but it'd be better simply to use `-lglfw`. This will use `libglfw.so` which I assume is a symlink to `libglfw.so.3` which is a symlink to `libglfw.so.3.2`. You can do `ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so*` to see links. You can use `ldd glad` to see `.so` dependencies.

Comment: @zxxc You are right! It is a symlink. I didn't know what a symlink was but now I know thanks to you. Glad that I can just simply bind -lglfw. And I think your guess is right, because in Mac, the library file name was libglfw.3.2.dylib not libglfw.dylib.3.2. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @zxxc's comment, linking -lglfw was a symlink to libglfw.so.3.2 after all. And his guess is plausible, since Mac had the extension(.dylib) at the end of the file name, not in the middle as (.so) files do in Linux.